# meaning of ブラバン

Tags: nouns, abbreviations, song

I came across this phrase in a song I recently listened to:

> ブラバンが プーとラッパを吹いた.

I've not been able to find out what ブラバン means, researching I found it might mean "music band" but I'm not sure how to directly translate the sentence, it doesn't make much sense.
Any answer would be a great help, thank you!

Btw the song is Tender Animals by Yura Yura Teikoku.

Answer (score 4):

ブラバン is short for [ブラスバンド](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89), or "[brass band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_band)".